# Find length of the longest contiguous subsequence of the same character

Tags: java, debugging, response

I am trying to find the longest repetitive subsequence of contiguous characters from a string.

```
public int longestRep(String str) {

}
```

When you call the method with

```
longestRep("ccbbbaaaaddaa"); //Should return 4
```

The code I have used thus far is;

```
public static int longestRep(String str)
{
    int currLen = 1; // Current length of contiguous chars being held in str
    char currLet = ' '; // Current Letter *NOT NEEDED FOR CODINGBAT
    char maxLet = ' '; // Maximum length letter *NOT NEEDED FOR CODINGBAT
    int maxLen = 0; // Maximum length of contiguous chars being held in str
    //int maxCount = 0; // Highest count of contiguous chars being held in str
    int currPos = 0; // Track where in str we are at
    int strLen = str.length(); // Length of str;
    for(currPos = 0; currPos < strLen -1 ; currPos++)
    {
        currLet = str.charAt(currPos);
        //System.out.println("Curr char: "+currLet+"  Next Char: "+str.charAt(currPos+1));
        if(currLet == str.charAt(currPos+1))
        {
            currLen++;
        }
        if(currLen > maxLen)
        {
            maxLen = currLen;
            //System.out.println("Max len: "+maxLen+"  Curr Len: "+currLen);
            //maxLet = currLet;
            currLen = 1;
        }
        boolean atBeginning = true;
        if(currPos == 0)
        {
            atBeginning = true;
        }
        else if(currPos != 0)
        {
            atBeginning = false;
        }
        if(atBeginning == false) //if not at the beginning of the string
        {
            if(currLet != str.charAt(currPos+1) && currLet == str.charAt(currPos-1))
            {
                currLen++;
            }
        }
        if(currLen > maxLen)
        {
            maxLen = currLen;
            currLen = 1;
        }
    }

    return maxLen;
  }
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int result = longestRep("abcdeeefeeeefppppppp");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

However, I am getting invalid responses and am unsure what I have done wrong.
I am a newbie to Java. Some of the code I have only just written and may/may not be being used.

Comment: Define `"invalid responses"` please.

Comment: [Stackoverflow search: Java longest sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+longest+sequence+)

Comment: you can initialize atBeginning like this: boolean atBeginning = (currPos == 0); or better yet you could just get rid of it altogether and use if(currPos != 0) instead of if(atBeginning == false)

Comment: All the stuff after `boolean atBeginning = true;` seems to be unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't make heads nor tails of any thing after `boolean atBeginning = true;` and frankly, it doesn't seem to be required...

Your basic logic should follow something like...

```
if character_at_current_position is equal to next_character then
    currLen = currLen + 1
else if currLen is greater then maxLen then
    maxLen = currLen
    currLen = 1
else currLen = 1
```

You would also need to perform another check for `currLen is greater then maxLen` outside the loop to account for any changes the last character might make

More like...

```
for (currPos = 0; currPos < strLen - 1; currPos++) {
    currLet = str.charAt(currPos);
    //System.out.println("Curr char: "+currLet+"  Next Char: "+str.charAt(currPos+1));
    if (currLet == str.charAt(currPos + 1)) {
        currLen++;
    } else if (currLen > maxLen) {
        maxLen = currLen;
        currLen = 1;
    } else {
        currLen = 1;
    }
}
if (currLen > maxLen) {
    maxLen = currLen;
}
```

So using

```
System.out.println(longestRep("ccccccaaaabbbbb")); // 6 c's
System.out.println(longestRep("ccbbbaaaaddaa")); // 4 a's
System.out.println(longestRep("abcdeeefeeeeeeeefppppppp")); // 8 e's
```

I get...

```
6
4
8
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public int longestRep(String s){
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
    int amt = 0;
    char current;
    int  max=0;

    for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i ++){
         if(current == c[i])
             amt ++;
         else{

             amt = 1;
             current = c[i];
         }
         if (max < amt) 
              max=amt;
    }

    return max;
}
```

This will iterate your string and check if the character at `i` is the same as the current character, if it is it will add one to `amt` or else it will set the current to that `char` and set `amt` to 1.

Comment: Would you now like to supply a version that compiles and works...